# IONIC build PROD

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to build my app for production.

> Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider
>   replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
>   function, resolving symbol Injectable in
>   /Users/rossrawlins/Desktop/Work/EngagementFactory/MobileEvent_V2.0/node_modules/@ionic/cloud-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/metadata.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol OpaqueToken in
>   /Users/rossrawlins/Desktop/Work/EngagementFactory/MobileEvent_V2.0/node_modules/@ionic/cloud-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol OpaqueToken in
>   /Users/rossrawlins/Desktop/Work/EngagementFactory/MobileEvent_V2.0/node_modules/@ionic/cloud-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts

I get the above error and I cannot work out how to resolve this.

below is my current config.

> global packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
> Cordova CLI      : 6.5.0 
> Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
> @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
> @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
> Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.3.1
> Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.4.1
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Node       : v6.9.4
> OS         : macOS Sierra
> Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002 
> ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
> ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
> npm        : 3.10.10
> ```

Below is my package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "EventsFactory",
  "version": "2.6.788",
  "author": "Engagement Factory",
  "homepage": "https://engagementfactory.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/calendar": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/geofence": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/linkedin": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.2",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.2.0",
    "angular2-qrcode": "^2.0.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.4.0",
    "azure-mobile-apps-client": "^2.0.1",
    "azure-query-js": "git+https://github.com/Azure/azure-query-js.git",
    "esprima": "^3.1.3",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ionic-angular": "3.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment-range": "^3.0.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "ng2-img-fallback": "^0.2.1",
    "ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.4",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.4.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.1",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js"
  },
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "EventsFactory: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: can you add your package.json?

Comment: try using the latest `cloud-angular` package.. `npm install @ionic/cloud-angular@latest --save` https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cloud-angular/issues/46

Comment: This causes MORE build errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that they have just released an update and that resolved the build issue.

update to 0.12.0